# Update Website Text that needs to contain Dynamic Data / Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently in the process of re-creating our schools website, as it's predecessor was quite painful to navigate / maintain.

We currently have an MS SQL Server with all of the data needed for the dynamic stuff.

My main issue is that ALL the website text needs to be editable by management, but in the middle of the text there may be a custom control (or dynamic data but that is not my issue). I was originally thinking of allowing a place holder and then having the server scan the text and replacing it with a web user control, however this has proved to be very difficult and probably bad practice.

I have spent almost a day searching Google attempting to find a solution but have had no luck with anything I have found.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to solve it with place holder syntax where you define a placeholder in the content that you can replace on the server.

One option is nustache https://github.com/jdiamond/Nustache

It will let you specify place holders like this: `{{FirstName}}`